# ¿Cómo puedo generar un reporte PDF en Smart Devices con Genexus Evo 3 U6?

Tags: android, pdf, genexus

Tengo una aplicación donde puedo crear y guardar formularios y ahora necesito generar un reporte en PDF que muestre y/o almacene en el dispositivo.

La aplicación está generada para Android.

Cualquier información relacionada sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: Hola @J.Diaz. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta describiéndo qué investigaste y la parte de tu código relevante para el reporte, junto a lo que hayas intentado? Quizás te interese leer [ask] para ver cómo se puede mejorar la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Hace un tiempo tuve el mismo problema.
Estoy desarrollando una app de ventas y tenia que poder generar un pdf con el dispositivo desconectado.

logre una solución partiendo de un html y publique lo que hice en el market

https://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?html2pdf,en

Hay un txt dentro del zip de como usarlo

Básicamente lo que hace este external object es crear un pdf en base a código html

el html puede ser complejo y manejar inline css
para que te hagas una idea yo hice un contrato de servicios con todos los colores e imágenes del cliente.

```
&html = '........'

&boolean = &HTMLTOPDF.create(&Html,&PathDispositivo)

true //Todo ok
false // no lo pudo crear por algún motivo
```

Comment: Tendras alguna solicion para el genexu 15? Saludos.